# Deploy a Redis cluster in Kubernetes with High Availability

Tags: kubernetes, cluster, high-availability, redis

I am looking at deploying a Redis cluster (3masters, 3workers/slaves) on Kubernetes.
I found the [Redis Operator](https://operatorhub.io/operator/redis-operator) as being the best option but the “capability level” doesn’t look that attractive to me.
There is the possibility to use the [Helm chart from Bitnami](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis-cluster) but not convinced by the “102vulnerabilities found”

[Operator capability level img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg6PD.png)

[102 vulnerabilities found img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7wTy.png)